# Using Pandas shift() in a Python for loop

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I am trying to plot historical stock quotes on a graph with years overlapping. I have used the shift() function successfully but can't make shift() work inside a for loop and years show up one after the other . I use the following script for better or for worse.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)+1, 12): #from 0 to end step 12
    dfx = df.loc[i:i+11]
    dfx.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    dfx = dfx.pct_change()
    dfx = dfx.tshift(-i) #shifting
    dfx['Close'].plot(ax=ax1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your indentation is missing. Is this what your actual code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there was nothing wrong with shift(). The dataframe was getting indexed by Date after the shift and I just needed to reset the index.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)+1, 12): #from 0 to end step 12    
    dfx = df.loc[i:i+11]
    dfx.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    dfx = dfx.tshift(-100) #shifting
    **dfx = dfx.reset_index()**
```

..but now It's not showing the Dates on the x axis, aghrrr...